# Evenly distribute boxes but with margin between each

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

Here is a fiddle from a similar question:
http://jsfiddle.net/DougCassidy/Gawe7/
It works pretty well, however, I'd like to have some nice spacing between the boxes. It would be good if the right margin were treated as a minimum spacing between boxes so that if the spacing were to fall below that amount, it would move everything down a row.  Also, there should be no right margin on whichever is currently the last box in a row.

And then, some bottom margin.  Either a fixed amount would be ok, or an amount equal to the current horizontal spacing might be nice, also.

```
$(new Array(9).join('<div class="invisible"></div>\n')).insertBefore('.stretch');

$(window).on('resize', function() {
$('#container').height($('.box').last().position().top +     $('.box').last().outerHeight());

//make it still justify when there's only one row
if ($('.box').first().position().top == $('.box').last().position().top) {
    $('.invisible').hide();
} else {
    $('.invisible').show();
}
}).resize();
```

Comment: Does it have to work that way for any reason? The performance is awful and I'm not clear looking at your question why you need javascript at all to achieve this.

Comment: It's a thumbnail gallery that I want to be responsive.  The colored boxes would be img thumbnails in real life. The current fiddle would be good enough except for the spacing between the boxes.  I need to have margins that act as minimum margins.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript for this, just negative margins:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/iHGCd

```
.gallery {
  margin: -5px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  .gallery {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.gallery img {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Because margins don't collapse on flex items, it works best if you add margins on all sides like this.

Comment: Works in chrome, not in FF25.

Comment: That's because Firefox doesn't support wrapping with Flexbox.  Negative margins are still the solution even if you aren't using Flexbox:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/dwbHi

Comment: You used the "flexbox" tag, I assumed you understood that you were asking about http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/, which Firefox only has a partial implementation of.

Comment: I used that as I figured there might be a js script that would coax browsers into doing the right thing, wrt flexbox.  I havent looked into it much because of browser support, but I have learned enough to know that flex box would be the answer, if browser support.  What I 'dont get' is why you are giving me codepens that dont work in ff.  I 'dont get' why that would be of use to me.

Comment: I suggest you take your issues regarding my pens not working in Firefox to the Mozilla team, since the fault is with them.  If a Flexbox answer is not what you're actually looking for, I recommend dropping the flexbox tag from your question.